# python/django - "Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed"

Tags: python, django, pip, python-imaging-library

I'm joining a project, so I want to set up the environnment, so what I did is :

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This fully installed all requirements including django 1.7.0, Pillow 2.4.0 and some others.

Then I want to build the database :

```
python manage.py migrate
```

And boom, error, I get the following :

```
CommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
stu.chan.icon: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install pillow".
stu.chan.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install pillow".
stu.Piec.icon: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install pillow".
```

... like I didn't install Pillow. 
So I checked the installed package (with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules) technique), and `Pillow 2.4.0` IS installed.

Then, I also tried to force reinstall : `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall Pillow==2.4.0`

But, nothing to do I get the same error when running `migrate`.

I'm using `python 3.4.0` and `django 1.7.0` on a mac OS X 10.6.7 wrapped in `virtualenv 1.11.6` with pip downgraded to `pip 1.2.1` (because of some well-known-yet-not-fully-resolved-nor-understood [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294997/pip-connection-failure-cannot-fetch-index-base-url-http-pypi-python-org-simpl) with pip and ssl).

All of the code above is within virtualenv (`bin/activate` done).

Do you have any ideas on why this problem and how to resolve it?

**- - - - - - EDIT - - - - - -**

When I run the above force-reinstall command, (so many code gets outpouted I can't paste it all but) although it finishes with "Successfully installed Pillow", there's some warnings in the code :

```
building 'PIL._imaging' extension
 (blabla code)
    _imaging.c:975:13: warning: array index of '1' indexes past the end of an array (that contains 1 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
        value = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(xy, 1);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/include/python3.4m/tupleobject.h:58:34: note: instantiated from:
    #define PyTuple_GET_ITEM(op, i) (((PyTupleObject *)(op))->ob_item[i])
                                     ^
    /usr/local/include/python3.4m/tupleobject.h:27:5: note: array 'ob_item' declared here
        PyObject *ob_item[1];
        ^
    1 warning generated.

(blabla code)
   libImaging/Unpack.c:867:1: warning: unused function 'copy3' [-Wunused-function]
    copy3(UINT8* out, const UINT8* in, int pixels)
    ^
    1 warning generated.
```

Comment: you get an any error while installing pillow..?

Comment: I updated the question. Please look at the warnings during the installation.

Comment: using `sudo` no warning ?

Comment: Do you have PIL installed? Sometimes, you need to uninstall PIL first and then install pillow.

Comment: @rajasimon : same warnings with sudo because I'm in virtualenv

Comment: @abrunet : I don't know if it is installed. How could I know?

Comment: with pip, `sudo pip uninstall pil` should do the trick..

Comment: Didn't work because pil is not found. pip install pil didn't work either. But I found the solution, I'll post it.

Comment: use Python 3.6.1rc1 - 2017-03-05, Download Windows x86-64 executable installer, install this and next >pip install pillow, but not use Python 3.6.1 - 2017-03-21, becose pillow not install. I no understend why. Sory for uncorrect word, i am rus)
p.s. this for windows 10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried :

- Reinstall globaly PIL by compiling "Imaging-1.1.7" using some instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398701), but didn't work
- Reinstall Pillow and it's dependency globally using [that link](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#mac-os-x-installation), but didn't work
- Reinstall GCC4.2 using [this link](http://caiustheory.com/install-gcc-421-apple-build-56663-with-xcode-42/), but it didn't work

I finally figured out I was in the case described in the wonderfull answer to [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35013/64-bit-support-with-a-32-bit-kernel-in-os-x-snow-leopard). In other words, I am running a mac whose CPU is capable of 64bit but whose kernel firmware is set to 32bit. Which is a problem as the project I'm working on was built for 64bit.

As explained in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944228/python-build-using-wrong-version-of-gcc-on-os-x), when you install python3 using an installer (DMG) it will sniff if the kernel is set to 32 bit and install 32bit version of python 3 accordingly. But if you just download the tarball source from python's website and install it with :

```
cd Python-3.4.1
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then the 64bit version of python3 should be installed. Which you can verify by doing :

```
file /usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

That done, all problems are gone with PIL/Pillow in the virtualenv using this 64bit version of python3. Even the pip downgrade became unnecessary.

Comment: PIL needs 64 bit instead of 32?

Answer (score 38):

I was having this problem on a Mac with Python 3.6.4.  The solution was to uninstall Pillow 5.1.0 and instead install 5.0.0.

```
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow==5.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This actually solved my problem after trying several ways. But Why Pillow5.1.0 caused this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I was too getting same problem while implememnting Image Upload using CLoudinary , but found the Above answer, but in some other way.

```
 sudo pip uninstall PIL

 sudo pip uninstall Pillow

 sudo pip install Pillow
```

After that mine Problem was solved !

Answer (score 4):

## For those who faced this issue with alpine-based image in docker;

Pillow requires these os level modules(for installation)

> gcc
> musl-dev
> jpeg-dev
> zlib-dev
> libjpeg

You probably delete these modules after install your python packages but, for use Pillow without issue, it requires **libjpeg**
Unless, Django raise with error:

> Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.

So add this module in Dockerfile(or don't uninstall):

```
RUN apk add libjpeg
```

works for me

Comment: this isn't clear. You list several packages as required at first, but then the rest of the answer sounds like only `libjpeg` is required.

Comment: In Dockerfile we add some modules to install our python packages. After install python packages, we remove these os level modules to reduce container's size. Because we don't need them generally after our packages installed. But for my side, i faced the error 'Pillow is not installed..' even i already installed. Django can't recognize the pillow because it dependent with libjpeg to use(not just install, also use). The solution is don't remove the libjpeg module (or add this again after clear your modules like i mention) in Dockerfile. @user17242583

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem, and my solution was much simpler:

Apparently packages PIL and Pillow can't coexist. **If you want to use Pillow you first have to uninstall PIL and then install Pillow**.

If you are on Mac, you have to install a few libraries as well using brew. Mentioned below is the sequence of steps:

```
$pip uninstall PIL
$brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
$pip install Pillow
```

To test if pillow is installed and ready to use, open python interpreter and try to import the following:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
```

*note that the library still says PIL but now it is importing from Pillow instead of PIL.

If you are able to successfully import then you are good to go (in all probability you won't have to worry about setting PYTHONPATH or 32/64-bit installations)

Source: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: The comment 'to test if pillow is installed [...] `from PIL import Image`' is very helpful - in my case it returns more detailed debugging info about an ImportError related to libjpeg.

Answer (score 2):

macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
My solution was

```
pip3 install Pillow
```

Not

```
pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why, but uninstalling and then reinstalling Pillow (***same version***) solved this problem for me.

```
python -m pip uninstall Pillow
python -m pip install Pillow
```

The Pillow version was 7.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason,

```
pip install pillow
```

wasnt working.
so I went to the official site of pillow and used

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pillow
```

which solved my issue of installing pillow.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve mine by going to this link in the docs:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Answer: PILLOW VERSION WILL NOT WORK IN A PYTHON VERSION IT WAS NOT MADE FOR!

So I had to check the chart. I was running django on python==3.9.13, so I needed to uninstall the pillow==7.2.0 to Install pillow==8.3.1 for my python version 3.9.13 and Boom it started working.

[image]

I did this:

```
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow==8.3.1
```

OR

```
python -m pip uninstall Pillow
python -m pip install Pillow==8.3.1
```

So it all depends on the python version you are running pillow on.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error using PyCharm's debugger.  I had to go to Settings->'Project Interpreter' highlight 'Pillow' and hit the little up arrow on the right to upgrade it.  Then the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

In your 'site-packages' file, download your desired pillow (.whl) file, then install it using command, 'pip install "directory"'.

I have seen that this error occurs due to wrong version of pillow, in term of bit installation in my case.

If you have 32 bit machine then you have to download 32 bit Pillow.
If you have 64 bit machine then you have to download 64 bit Pillow.

In my case I was using Visual Studio but when I tried to install Pillow using PyCharm then it downloaded and installed suitable Pillow version automatically which work was not being done by Visual Studio automatically.

Visual Studio was installing Pillow wrong version again and again many times when I was trying to install Pillow by uninstalling.
Basically it was fetching .whl file from cache file I guess.

Answer (score 0):

For python3 make sure your `$PYTHONPATH` has the `virtualenv` path and 
Instead of running the command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Run:

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pillow 4.1.0 with Python 3.6.0 then upgrading the Python version will fix this issue.
Found the solution here: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2479#issuecomment-292252147

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my virtual environment, even though Pillow was installed. Also installing a lower version didn't help. As soon I left my virtual environment it worked. Maybe this is helping someone.

There is the command:

```
    (wb_env) C:\Users\Taranis\Dropbox\08_Coding\Python 
    Coding\Programme\Projekt_Webblog\tim_webblog>python manage.py makemigrations app_webblog
```

The error:

```
    SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

    ERRORS:
    app_webblog.BlogEntry.entry_img: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because 
    Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "pip install 
    Pillow".
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to uninstall Pillow from user folder and install it with `sudo`.

Initial install was:

```
$ pip3 install Pillow --user
```

installed to: `~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Pillow-7.0.0.dist-info`

So first uninstalled it and then installed with `sudo`:

```
$ pip3 uninstall Pillow
$ sudo pip3 install Pillow
```

new location: `/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/Pillow-7.0.0.dist-info` and problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## Window users

### First Uninstall Pip

```
pip uninstall Pillow
```

### Then Install it Again

```
pip install Pillow
```

## Ubuntu users

### First Uninstall Pip

```
sudo pip uninstall Pillow
```

### Then Install it Again

```
sudo pip install Pillow
```

I Hope It will works for you

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me,

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev -y
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev -y
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev -y
sudo apt-get install liblcms1-dev -y
sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7 -y
sudo apt-get install libtiff5 -y
```

You probably have some of them installed but not all. For me, some of them weren't and that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might get **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'**

This could be because you added it to your installed_apps in *settings.py*

---

### To solve this:

Just remove it from installed_apps or change it to "PIL"

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # installed apps
    'pillow',
]
```

to this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # installed apps
    'PIL',
]
```

If you just comment it out,

```
# 'pillow'
```

you will still get **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'**

so make sure you delete it completely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding on a raspberry with a lite os, this fixed my bug :

```
sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7-dev
```

Good Luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Got similar issue, I was running django in a virtual environment.

```
pip install Pillow
```

command installed Pillow but django was not recognising it.

This solved the issue for me:

```
python3 -m pip install Pillow
```

Initially I got issue when I tried running the pip command using `python -m`
but then I installed pip using python3

```
  curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

   python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

and then ran `python3 -m pip install Pillow`

Answer (score 0):

1. pip uninstall Pillow
2. Then Press, Y
3. After that, pip ins

Answer (score 0):

you just install pillow in your (venv) not in your main python path. you have to use poweshell or commandline of pycharm (for example).

Answer (score 0):

i just do to add pillow in Project Settings-->Python interpreter and download

Comment: What platform, Windows 10? if so, you should state which python version you have this working on

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Pillow but the error is persisting  , This will solve the problem

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS Code, try to restart the editor. It works (for me).