# Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed

Tags: python, django, windows, visual-studio, python-imaging-library

```
CommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
estore.Header.img: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "python -m pip install pillow".
products.Product.img: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "python -m pip install pillow".
```

I have latest version of Pillow installed (7.2.0)

```
requirement already satisfied pillow in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (7.2.0)
```

I m using python version 3.8.5, visual studio version v16.7.0 and Django 3.1
Please help me!

Comment: show the output of `pip freeze | grep -iE '(django|pil)'`

Comment: asgiref==3.2.10
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==19.3.0
colorama==0.4.3
Django==3.1
django-mysql==3.8.1
iniconfig==1.0.1
install==1.3.3
more-itertools==8.4.0
mysqlclient @ file:///C:/mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
olefile==0.46
packaging==20.4
Pillow==7.2.0
pluggy==0.13.1
psycopg2==2.8.5
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
py==1.9.0
PyMySQL==0.10.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==6.0.1
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
toml==0.10.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python/django - "Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662073/python-django-cannot-use-imagefield-because-pillow-is-not-installed)

Answer (score 1):

Try to install pillow in your virtual environment!

cmd:

```
workon [your virtual env]
pip install Pillow
```

if this does not work try this:

```
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow==5.0.0
```

Comment: It gives error on installing: 
RuntimeWaring: Pillow does not yet support Python 3.8 and does not yet provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.

Comment: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade pillow

Comment: Successfully installed but giving same error when trying migrations

Comment: You mean, if you manage.py makemigrations, you get this error: "products.Product.img: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed" ? Can you share your virtual env with us? -pip freeze

Comment: asgiref==3.2.10
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==19.3.0
colorama==0.4.3
Django==3.1
django-mysql==3.8.1
iniconfig==1.0.1
install==1.3.3
more-itertools==8.4.0
mysqlclient @ file:///C:/mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
olefile==0.46
packaging==20.4
Pillow==7.2.0
pluggy==0.13.1
psycopg2==2.8.5
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
py==1.9.0
PyMySQL==0.10.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==6.0.1
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
toml==0.10.1

Comment: you can try to use antoher pillow version -pip install Pillow==2.2.2

Comment: "microsoft visual c++ 14.0 is required get it with microsoft visual c++ build tools"

when trying to install Pillow==2.2.2

Answer (score -1):

I think I will be able able to answer this.
My system info are follows:

- Windows 10
- Django version 3.2
- Python version 3.7

I found on the Pillow documentation that the tested Pillow version is 7.1.0
You can read [here.](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#other-platforms)
for this, you need to launch cmd or anaconda prompt and type

```
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow==7.1.0
```