# Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed when it is in fact installed

Tags: python, django, django-models, pip, python-imaging-library

Hello I've been trying to add an ImageField for one of my models in my Django app.
When I ran the following code:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

A statement came out, saying I needed to install Pillow, which I did ('Successfully installed Pillow-8.2.0').

However, when I tried to run makemigrations again, the following error occurred:

```
(fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
```

I am aware that there are several threads out there that have discussed similar issues (like [python/django - "Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662073/python-django-cannot-use-imagefield-because-pillow-is-not-installed)) and I have tried doing whatever was recommended (reinstalling 64-bit Python, upgrading pip, making sure I don't have PIL, attempting to install an older Pillow version) but none worked.

Particularly, attempting to install an older Pillow version caused errors with the following message:

```
Pillow 7.1.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries.
```

I am using Windows 10, Python 3.9, Django 3.2.0 and Pillow 8.2.0 . Would really appreciate it if anyone can help me with this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

first of all; there are some questions to be clear in order to provide input for it. Questions like;
1- Do you activated your virtualenv,
2- How did you check if Pillow installed correctly?
.......
normally, activate virtualenv and then, run the command

```
pip freeze
```

this will list down all of installed packages.

Comment: wait so am I supposed to install Pillow with my virtual environment activated or not? If I do so, then yes when 'pip freeze' is run, then Pillow==8.2.0 would be listed there as well. But when I run makemigrations, the same error occurs

Comment: yes. activate your virtualenv. env is the container like. that is inside is accessible. activate your env and run pip freeze. see if Pillow is listed. if not. run command ``` pip install Pillow```

Comment: yes i already did that and Pillow is already listed, unfortunately when I run makemigrations again, the error is not fixed

Comment: could you provide all the code and errors. your model, and error.

Answer (score -2):

Just type

pip3 install pillow

Hope this works

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't for me :(